# How to create a conditional Statement with a group of variables in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I have 4 variables which I need to check in a single `if` statement.

For example:

```
If Not (strId = "" And strTermId = "") Or Not (strMDF <> "" And strPCPTermId <> "")
```

In the above statement only 2 variables consist of values and the other two have no values.

Is the above statement correct or not?

If not, how to group the variables and make "(,)" work in VB.Net?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you wrote the if statement is incredibly confusing to read. I prefer to use the not equal to operator ( or <> ). I would write it like this:

```
If (strId <> "" And strTermId <> "") Or (strMDF = "" And strPCPTermId = "") Then
```

The statement is saying that if the first two variables are not blank, OR, the second two variable are blank, the if statement will be true.